# Кнопки налезают на header при уменьшении страницы

Tags: html, css, прокрутка

Скажите пожалуйста как настроить scroll чтобы при уменьшении страницы кнопки не нализали на header.

у меня такая структура

без css стилей вот сам скелет

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="class1">
    <header class="class2">
        <div class="text_block">
            <div id="txt_block">
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="buttons_block">
        <form action="">
            <input type="submit" value="do"/>
        </form>
        <form action="">
            <input type="submit" value="do"/>
        </form>
        <form action="">
            <input type="submit" value="do"/>
        </form>
        <form action="">
            <input type="submit" value="do"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

вот как выглядит когда я сжимаю страницу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

кнопки наползают на текст выше.

можно ли как то подключить склол чтобы он выправлял ситуацию?

Comment: Приложите ваш css

Comment: скорее всего у header задана высота.